# IFTTT pointing to wrong Facebook page

Tags: facebook, if-this-then-that

I'm trying to get automatic messages in my Discord server using web hooks and IFTTT, but it's automatically pointing to the wrong fan-page and I don't know how to change it. I tried this:

Services -> Facebook pages -> Settings -> Edit connection

But it keeps saying

> The requested page or file does not exist. Explore Applet collections instead!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you'll have more luck with their support, they can give you a more detail error message if such exists

Comment: I have the same issue: there is no way to "edit connection" once it has been set up... I tried to create another account and this did not work either. It looks like there is a deep issue there.

Comment: @davidbourguignon i remember solving this by changing the pages order in my profile so the one I wanted for ifttt was first

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to this problem.

- Go to your Facebook profile > Settings > Business integrations > you will see all the apps connected to your profile including IFTTT.
- Click on 'view and edit'.
- A pop up window will show you section "What business features can be managed".
- Your pages are listed there and all those managed by IFTTT are ticked off.
- Tick off the page you want IFTTT to manage and click Save.
- Go back to IFTTT, click EDIT again and now a menu will show up with all your pages you allowed IFTTT to manage.

Took me forever to figure this out.